# Weird exception when trying to use Dependency Injection in an Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, azure-functions

Given a File->New->Azure Functions v2 App, I'm trying to get a reference to either an `ILoggerFactory` or an `ILogger<T>`.

I'm doing this in the `StartUp.cs` class which is ran on the function app start.

Given the following code a weird exception is thrown:

```
var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

with the following exception:

[image]

```
 A host error has occurred
[27/02/2019 8:21:22 AM] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider
```

What is going on?

The full test repo/code can be [found here on GitHub](https://github.com/PureKrome/TestFunctionsApp).

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but well into the execution of the function, in a service which I have injected for the Azure Function to use. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: The same here. Could you figure out what caused this error message?

Comment: Did you figure out your issue @AnthonyPotts? I just upgraded a function from V2 to V3 and am having this issue now also well into the execution of the function

Comment: @Adrian No, I ended up using the IOC that I had hand rolled from a couple of blog posts.

Comment: We had the same problem trying to access our logger in Startup. We ended up registering it twice, one within a logger factory: `var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder => // register your loggers for use in Startup here again);`

Answer (score 7):

It seems that some infrastructure (e.g. `IFileLoggingStatusManager`) necessary for `HostFileLoggerProvider` is not set up yet at the time you are creating the dependency injection container and attempt to resolve the logger in the StartUp class. I think you should delay logging until after the application has fully started.

If you look at the startup code of WebJobs you'll see that the logger gets added [first](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L70), after that [the external startup gets executed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L111) and finally the [required logging services](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L155) gets added. Which is the wrong order for your case.

Comment: Henk: Do you know about a workaround for this sitaution? I would like to be able to inject the ILogger to a dependency which is bootstrapped in Startup (builder.Services.AddSingleton...) 
preferably as part of the Startup in my Azure Function

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/749): "You can't request an ILogger<> during service initialization -- some of the loggers haven't had all of their dependencies registered at this point." In [this post](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/536) it is suggested to use the [Humble Objects](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) design pattern instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution for a while then I end up creating another service container for the startup class, but it'll need to register the required services to this container.

```
   public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
           var services = builder.Services;
           IConfiguration configuration = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
           var tempServiceContainer = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddScoped(_ => configuration);
           tempServiceContainer.AddSingleton<IYourService, YourService>();
        }
    }
```

Or maybe you could try using lazy Dependency Injection, but I haven't test it yet on the cloud server.

```
service.AddSingleton<IYourService, YourService>();
service.AddSingleton(provider => new Lazy<IYourService>(provider.GetService<IYourService>));

var yourService = serviceProvider.GetService<Lazy<IYourService>>();
```

Comment: @infansoetedja this question is really old now. Also, Azure Functions are up to version 4 (this question was targeting v2). Are you still having a problem? have you tried working with v4 Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, at least not yet. ([link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5782))

The services getting registered at startup are not fully ready to be used inside the Configure method itself. Read the section 'Caveats' here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

> "The startup class is meant for only setup and registration. Avoid
> using services registered at startup during the startup process. For
> instance, don't try to log a message in a logger that is being
> registered during startup. This point of the registration process is
> too early for your services to be available for use. After the
> Configure method is run, the Functions runtime continues to register
> additional dependencies, which can affect how your services operate."