# Is it valid to inject db initialization and seed into Azure function startup?

Tags: c#, azure

In my ASP.NET Core app Iused the following code to initialize and seed database, especially for testing. Example below.

ASP.NET Core example:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string entityName = $"Data Source=master_data.{typeof(TTestedEntity).Name}.db";

            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                services.AddDbContext<MasterDataContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlite(entityName);
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                using (IServiceScope scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    IServiceProvider scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    MasterDataContext db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MasterDataContext>();
                    ILogger<DiLibMasterDataWebApplicationFactory<TStartup, TTestedEntity>> logger = scopedServices
                        .GetRequiredService<ILogger<DiLibMasterDataWebApplicationFactory<TStartup, TTestedEntity>>>();

                    db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    MasterDataSeed.Seed(db);
                }
            });
```

I want to use something similar in Azure Durable Functions on my local machine for testing, playing purposes. But it cases this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900982/weird-exception-when-trying-to-use-dependency-injection-in-an-azure-function).
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) says the following.

Is the quoted text refers to that I want to do? I mean does it says that, `hey, coder, don't do that because there are other stuff you are not aware of and you might find yourself in a crazy situation!`

> The startup class is meant for only setup and registration. Avoid
>   using services registered at startup during the startup process. For
>   instance, don't try to log a message in a logger that is being
>   registered during startup. This point of the registration process is
>   too early for your services to be available for use. After the
>   Configure method is run, the Functions runtime continues to register
>   additional dependencies, which can affect how your services operate.

If no then what is the solution for this?

The error message linked above mention two types which aren't there. I haven't found these types anywhere.

```
private void ConfigureControlPanel(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ControlPanelContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
                });
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ModuleValidator>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IControlPanelBusinessLogic, ControlPanelBusinessLogic>();

            ServiceProvider sp = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (IServiceScope serviceScope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                IServiceProvider scopedServices = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

                ControlPanelContext controlPanelContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ControlPanelContext>();

                controlPanelContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                controlPanelContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                Module m1 = new Module { Name = "asd", Description = "asdd", ModuleRoute = "asd"};
                Module m2 = new Module { Name = "asd2", Description = "asdd2", ModuleRoute = "asd2"};

                controlPanelContext.Modules.Add(m1);
                controlPanelContext.Modules.Add(m2);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a hosted service and do your scoped functionality when it is started.

Comment: Sadly hosted services are not supported for Azure Functions.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but what did you end up doing as a solution? I am torn between either writing an explicit deployment script/project vs doing the setup steps in Startup like you are recommending above.

Comment: I ended up not using Durable Functions for other reasons. Probably the community have solutions for this. I haven't followed Durable Functions in the last 3 years.